# Importing Nodes with Coordinates to Gephi from CSV

Tags: csv, graph, gephi

This question seems pretty stupid but I actually fail to find a simple solution to this. I have a csv file that is structured like this:

```
0 21 34.00 34.00
1 23 35.00 25.00
2 25 45.00 65.00
```

The first column is the node's id, the second is an unimportant attribute. The 3rd and 4th attribute are supposed to be the x and y position of the nodes.
I can import the file into the Data Laboratory without problems, but I fail to explain to Gephi to use the x y attributes as the corresponding properties. All I want to achieve is that Gephi sets the x Property to the value of the x Attribute (and y respectively). Also see picture.

[image]
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Layout window, you can select "Geo Layout" and define which columns are used as Latitude and Longitude.

The projection might come in weird if you do not actually have GeoData, but for me, this is fine.

Answer (score 1):

In Gephi 0.8 there was a plugin called [Recast column](https://marketplace.gephi.org/plugin/recast-column/). This plugin is unfortunately not ported to Gephi 0.9 yet, but it allowed you to set Standard  (hidden) Columns in the Node Table, from visible values in the nodes table. Thus if you have two columns of type Float or Decimal that represent your coordinates, you could set the coordinate values of your nodes.